# I am getting an error "Pic is not a constructor"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, body-parser

I am getting an error "Pic is not a constructor".

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOWr1.png

Here is my schema for pics located in: Test\api\models\pic.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const picSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    cost: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});

mongoose.exports = mongoose.model('Pic', picSchema);
```

and this is my route located in: Test\api\routes\pics.js

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const Pic = require('../models/pic');
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');

    router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
        const pic = new Pic({
            _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
            name: req.body.name,
            cost: req.body.cost
        });
        const result = pic.save().then(result => {
            console.log(results);
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
        res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Handling POST requests to /pics',
            createdPic: pic
          });
    });
    module.exports = router;
```

The following is my app code located in: Test\app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uri = process.env.mongo;

mongoose.connect(uri ,{
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useNewUrlParser: true
})
.then(() => console.log('Mongodb connected...'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const picsRoutes = require('./api/routes/pics');
app.use('/pics',picsRoutes);

app.use((req,res,next) =>{
    const error = new Error('Not Found');
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(error.status || 500);
    res.json({
        error:{
            message: error.message
        }
      });
});

module.exports = app;
```

I have tried different ways of implementing the same and I keep getting the same error
What am I doing wrong and is there a better way use these objects?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the `../models/pic` file. It's written in a way that doesn't allow instanciating with `new Pic()`.

Comment: @PetrHejda I've added file locations please look at it.